# Kernel Module Core OS

Tags: github, module, linux-kernel, kernel, coreos

I am trying to build kernel modules for CoreOS but having issue with finding the right kernel source tree. The loaded kernel on my CoreOS vagrant image is "4.2.2-coreos-r1." I see many tags on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/coreos/linux/tree/v4.2.2-coreos), but not one corresponding to this version.

Can I be guided to the right tag and or repository?

Comment: Did you check that [one](https://github.com/coreos/linux/tree/v4.2.2-coreos)?

Comment: This worked .. thanks ... is there a way to get link to all releases of coreOS? I have another box with kernel version 4.1.6

Comment: Sorry, but this is only link I found. I am also curious, why it is only one there.